# find smiliarites from two audio files

Tags: python, audio, waveform, wave, librosa

I'm developing a Python project that should find similiarites from two audio wave. This waves are record from football match (spacifically, they are salient action) and I should see if the waves have (for example) same peaks when the soccer player can kick. I know that I use librosa, numpy, etc. But I don't know what type of feature I should find for compare them.
I hope that you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can look up [MFCC and Mel spectogram](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-to-know-the-mel-spectrogram-31bca3e2d9d0)

Comment: What should the output of your program be. Not quite sure what kind of similarity you are looking for

Comment: these are matches between soccer robots. I want see if is possible establilshes a rule that can say (for example) "if there is a growth of two decibel you can kick" but I don't know how I can find the same growth in my audio files